# Opening a VB6 project

Tags: vb6

I have a project sent to me by a friend to edit written in VB6.0, I have researched the web and cannnot find a solution on a way to open it. He wrote the code originally in  Visual Basic 6.0 Enterprise Edition but I cannot find a way of opening and editing the files. Any ideas?

Comment: You can also find copies of Visual Studio 6.0 (which includes VB6) on eBay, or google "bittorrent visual studio 6" to find some other options.

Comment: You need one of the original VB6 editions if you want to edit and run it. If you just want to read the code open it in any text editor.